# Loading animation doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-animations, loading

I want show loading div while my page fully loaded. CSS rotate features work  perfectly on Google Chrome but it is not working IE.

My CSS code and html code is below.

```css
/*Transparent*/
.tr_loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.tr_loading-wheel {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    
    border-width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
.style-2 .tr_loading-wheel {
    border-style: double;
    border-color: #ccc transparent;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tr_loading style-2">
    <div class="tr_loading-wheel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Following is an example of vendor prefixed code and is not supported by all browsers.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Use standard variant i.e:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

See detailed documentation for `@keyframes` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

**Working Demo:**

```css
/*Transparent*/
.tr_loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.tr_loading-wheel {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -40px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  border-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
.style-2 .tr_loading-wheel {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #ccc transparent;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tr_loading style-2">
    <div class="tr_loading-wheel"></div>
</div>
```